# Process substitution with read

Tags: bash

I want to print stuff to the screen separated by key presses (any key). A reduced version of what I'm trying to do is:

```
$ echo banana && read -rsn1 && echo orange && read -rsn1 && echo apple
```

That works fine in bash, as expected.

However, I would like to do that inside vim (i.e., open vim, print banana, wait for key press, print orange, wait for key press, print apple), so I thought I could use process substitution for that:

```
$ vim <(echo banana && read -rsn1 && echo orange && read -rsn1 && echo apple)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work: only banana is printed. It looks like it can't capture key presses and blocks there. Why not? What is going on? How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2):

I think the command you're looking for is

```
vim +"echo 'banana'" +"call getchar()" +"echo 'orange'" +"call getchar()" +"echo 'apple'"
```

The `+"..."` syntax allows to specify a vim command to execute after startup. Thus the line will use vim's `echo` to print the word in its command prompt followed by vim's `getchar()` which waits for a userinput (see [`:h getchar()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getchar%28%29))

Now why your command didn't worked I may be wrong but I think that `read` expects an input on stdin which isn't what you modify when you press a key in vim.